# Is there any way to force Java to recognize the unnamed package from a named package?

Tags: java, package, decompiling

In order to complete a project, I need to alter a class file in a named package.

I cannot put it into the unnamed package; it is imported itself from other classes.

I cannot put all the dependencies into named packages, they are also relied upon by other classes.

My goal is to force `javac` through whatever means necessary to allow imports from the unnamed package. It's bad practice, but I have no other choice.

Alternatively, how would I go about putting all of the imported classes into a package *without* recompiling them, reference that package in order to compile the target class, and then remove those references after the compile?

Comment: *the class in it's compiled (and thusly when decompiled) references packages in the unnamed package, from back when that was allowed.

Comment: Why do you have to force it? What's stopping you from importing the classes?

Comment: Question needs to be more clear.

Comment: Simply never use the unnamed package at all.

Comment: the classes that are being imported by the class I wish to modify are in the unnamed package. Either I put those classes into a package that can be seen from my modified class so it will compile (and then point it back towards the old versions after that business is done), or I find a way to force javac to allow the otherwise unallowed import.

Comment: @Andrew Older java versions allowed this without any fuss, so compiling your code against java 1.3 (maybe even 1.4) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I compiled the program by making barebones definitions of all classes and methods it imported inside a named package, and then used a program called Classeditor to edit out the package names/path after compiling.

Answer (score 1):

> how would I go about putting all of
>   the imported classes into a package
>   WITHOUT recompiling them

**You can't**, the package name is part of the full class name and present in the class-file itself.

You can use reflection to access these classes, this is a ugly solution for a ugly problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it was possible to import classes from the unnamed package into classes in named packages until java 1.4. However, that does not work anymore.

That is, if you have two classes like this:

```
File A.java
import b.B; // <-- This is ok
class A {
...
}

File B.java
package b;
import A; // <-- Does not compile after 1.4
class B {
...
}
```

then it would be possible to reference class B from class A but not the other way. You cannot import classes from the unnamed package.

You may try to compile your classes using JDK 1.3. They will still run in JDK 1.4 and above.

Comment: people keep saying "you cannot". But I want to do it anyway. Are there any reliable open source JDK that I can alter to take out that annoying little "feature" of java?

Comment: @Andrew You were given a perfectly workable solution as far as I can see.